# Проблема в реализации задачи на "Коня"

Tags: c++

Дана шахматная доска размером m*n. На каждой клеточке данной доски стоит число (числа могут быть как положительными, так и отрицательными). На данной доске стоит шахматный конь (в левой верхней клетке). Помогите коню добраться до правой нижней клетки данной доски и при этом собрать наибольшую сумму чисел. Конь может ходить только четырьмя способами: 2 клетки вправо и 1 вниз (x+2, y+1); 2 клетки вправо и 1 вверх (x+2, y-1); 2 клетки вниз и 1 вправо (x+1, y+2); 2 клетки вниз и 1 влево (x-1, y+2)
У меня проблема с ходом работы программы, тесты, которые я пробовал - проходят, вроде все возможные случаи хода коня учел, но всеравно есть ошибка, проблема не в кэшировании, у меня сайт выдает именно неправильное значение ответа, а не долгое время работы программы

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int h;
int w;
int Matrix[2001][2001];
int flag = 0;

long long int F(int n, int m)
{
    if ((n - 2 == 1 and m - 1 == 1) or (n - 2 == 1 and m + 1 == 1) or (n - 1 == 1 and m - 2 == 1) or (n + 1 == 1 and m - 2 == 1))
    {
        flag = 1;
        return Matrix[1][1] + Matrix[n][m];
    }
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and m - 2 >= 1 and n + 1 <= h and m + 1 <= w)
        return max(max(F(n - 1, m - 2), F(n - 2, m - 1)), max(F(n - 2, m + 1), F(n + 1, m - 2))) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and m - 2 >= 1 and n + 1 > h and m + 1 <= w)
        return max(max(F(n - 1, m - 2), F(n - 2, m - 1)), F(n - 2, m + 1)) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and m - 2 >= 1 and n + 1 <= h and m + 1 > w)
        return max(max(F(n - 1, m - 2), F(n - 2, m - 1)), F(n + 1, m - 2)) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and n - 1 <= h and n + 1 > h and m + 1 > w and m - 2 >= 1)
        return max(F(n - 1, m - 2), F(n - 2, m - 1)) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and m - 1 >= 1 and m - 2 < 1 and m + 1 <= w)
        return max(F(n - 2, m - 1), F(n - 2, m + 1)) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (m - 2 >= 1 and n - 1 >= 1 and n + 1 <= h and n - 2 < 1)
        return max(F(n - 1, m - 2), F(n + 1, m - 2)) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and m + 1 <= w and m + 2 > w and m - 1 < 1)
        return F(n - 2, m + 1) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (n - 2 >= 1 and m - 1 >= 1 and m - 2 < 1 and m + 1 > w)
        return F(n - 2, m - 1) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (m - 2 >= 1 and n - 1 >= 1 and n - 2 < 1 and n + 1 > h)
        return F(n - 1, m - 2) + Matrix[n][m];
    if (m - 2 >= 1 and n + 1 <= h and n + 2 > h and n - 1 < 1)
        return F(n + 1, m - 2) + Matrix[n][m];
    return INT_MIN;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j, res;
    cin >> n >> m;
    h = n;
    w = m;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            cin >> Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    if (n == 1 and m == 1)
        cout << Matrix[1][1];
    else
    {
        res = F(n, m);
        if (flag == 1)
            cout << res;
        else
            cout << "-";
    }
}
```

Comment: Если неправильный ответ, то вероятно неверно понято задание. Приведите его точную формулировку.

Comment: Дана шахматная доска размером m*n.  На каждой клеточке данной доски стоит число (числа могут быть как положительными, так и отрицательными). На данной доске стоит шахматный конь (в левой верхней клетке).  

Помогите коню добраться до правой нижней клетки данной доски и при этом собрать наибольшую сумму чисел. 

Конь может ходить только четырьмя способами: 

2 клетки вправо и 1 вниз (x+2, y+1); 

2 клетки вправо и 1 вверх (x+2, y-1); 

2 клетки вниз и 1 вправо (x+1, y+2); 

2 клетки вниз и 1 влево (x-1, y+2).

Comment: Ничего не понятно, точной однозначной постановки задачи нет, приведен какой-то код — ищите ошибку. Ну не задают так вопросы... А, пока писал, уже есть хоть какая-то постановка. Только внесите ее, пожалуйста, в сам вопрос. И добавьте еще и URL проверяющей системы, если таковой имеется (а судя по вашим словам, имеется).

Comment: Это задача с моего университета, там зарегистрированы только студенты этого вуза, так что вряд ли это имеет смысл

Comment: ттогда дайте хоть несколько тестовых примеров посмотреть :)

Comment: 3 3 

4 -1 3  

5 2 7  

-1 1 0

Comment: 4 4 

5 2 1 0 

1 0 0 0 

2 -1 3 0 

-1 0 1 7

Comment: 5
4
0
0
1
0
1
3
14
1
2
2
3
0
0
9
9
1
1
2
3
8

Comment: Ваши тесты, очевидно не покрывают всех написанных условий в дереве if-else. Проверить такое разлапистое дерево, ни у кого не хватит усидчивости. Попробуйте, вместо дерева относительного положения коня на поле, написать написать цикл по возможным направлениям движения коня. Это резко сократит число проверок, сделав аналитический поиск ошибки возможным.

Comment: Кстати, вы привели условия, но не ответы.